# How do I revert to a different version in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

Google tag manager is showing a previous version (31) as live. I want to have 32 live. How do I do this? 32 contains all the tags and triggers that should be firing on our site, as well as the activity history for each which is useful for us to manage changes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you rolled back to previous version ? If that is the case, just go to container, versions and than click on 3 dots all the way right and choose "set as latest version" if the version is not published click on "publish".